# Side-by-side Forest Plot in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

So this is some generic data. I currently use the metafor package and `par()` function to make the plots side by side. However, I would like to ideally get rid of the study column in the second graph and the log RR estimates from both plots. I would like both forest plots to be moved closer together as well. Sorry for not providing data previously - I'm new at this.

```
library(metafor)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

### load BCG vaccine data
data(dat.bcg)
### calculate log relative risks and corresponding sampling variances
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
### default forest plot of the observed log relative risks
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi)
### default forest plot of the observed log relative risks for second plot
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi)
```

===============================

Does anyone know how to make a side-by-side forest plot in r?
I want to have the subgroup names on the left hand side, then two forest plots immediately to the right (beside each other)
Somewhat like this http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v43/n8/images_article/ng.882-F1.jpg
but much simpler.

I have tried the `par()` function with metafor package but it does not work.

Comment: You really should show some sample data and the code you've tried (including what functions/packages you plan to use). Please read [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You could draw each individual forest plot using `ggplot` (**ggplot2**) and then use `grid.arrange` (**gridExtra**) to to bind tham together.

Comment: Yes, need sample data for this. Google has plenty on this too. This might get you started. 
http://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/forest-plots-in-r-ggplot-with-side-table/

Comment: I've looked at this for a while but none of the functions make this particularly easy. I've had to hack at the insides of the functions but it's still tricky to get everything to line up.

Comment: I dont necessarily need to use the metafor package...any package that can do the trick is fine by me.... Thanks for trying MrFlick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This gets you pretty close:

```
library(metafor)
data(dat.bcg)
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
par(mar=c(5,4,1,1))
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, annotate=FALSE, cex=.8, at=seq(-3,2,1), digits=1, xlim=c(-6,2))
text(0, 15, "Figure 1", cex=.8, font=2)
par(mar=c(5,3,1,2))
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, annotate=FALSE, slab=rep("",length(dat$yi)), cex=.8, at=seq(-3,2,1), digits=1, xlim=c(-5,3))
text(0, 15, "Figure 2", cex=.8, font=2)
```

[image: side-by-side forest plots]